# How to get rust version from wasm file?

Tags: system-building

In the Rust environment, if we can get a Wasm file, is it possible to know which Rust version? As I have tried, I need to use a different Rust SDK to compile and eventually find a matched Wasm hash. Is there any better way to accomplish this?